# Fetch information from mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql

**Updated script** with proper field names. Why isnt this working?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("bookorama", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM customers"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);     // You actually have to execute the $sql with mysql_query();

echo "<table>";  //start the table

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))  //Loop through the results
{
    //echo each row of the table
    echo "<tr>                              
            <td>$row['customerID']</td>
             <td>$row['name']</td>
            <td>$row['Aaddress']</td>
            <td>$row['city']</td>
          </tr>";
} 

echo '</table>';   //close out the table

?>
```

Comment: you don't actully run your query $sql, or retrieve the results from it. see the manual for: mysql_query(),mysql_fetch_assoc()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("bookorama", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM customers"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);     // You actually have to execute the $sql with mysql_query();

echo "<table>";  //start the table

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))  //Loop through the results
{
    //echo each row of the table
    echo "<tr>";                              
    echo "<td>$row['CustomerID']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['address']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['city']</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
} 

echo '</table>';   //close out the table

?>
```

Comment: this gives me an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on line 19

Comment: This still gives the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING  on line 19

Comment: Nvm, I fixed it myself. Thanks again @jondavidjohn

Answer (score 2):

You can [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to retriever the rows from you query.

For example using mysql_fetch_array:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table><tbody>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row[0] . "</td><td>" . $row[1] . "</td></tr>";  
}
echo "</tbody></table>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the query and loop through the results.

You are better off learning from day one about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

And also don't interpolate directly from any user submitted variables (that includes `$_POST`).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to do this when embedding anything more complex than scalars inside double quotes

```
 echo "<tr>                              
        <td>{$row['CustomerID']}</td>
        <td>{$row['address']}</td>
        <td>{$row['city']}</td>
      </tr>";
```

So whenever you have a more complex var name than "test $var" in quotes, wrap with {}  - and even then, it's good practice to wrap scalars too like "test {$var}"